# Adding a new member to our Google Admin Directory Group via API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk

Wow, I have searched high and low and can't find a hint of a "good" answer to this question. Which makes me believe its very easy and nobody is asking, and I am stupid, or nobody can figure it out.

When a user Joins our site, we want to during the new user injection process also add them to our google groups page. I have this code here, for listing users (was trying this just to get me started)

```
$start = microtime(true);
require_once __DIR__ . '/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8080';
$KEY_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json';
$TOKEN_FILE   = "token.txt";
$SCOPES = array(
  Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER
);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Testing stuff");
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_LOCATION);

// Incremental authorization
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setRedirectUri($REDIRECT_URI);
$client->setScopes($SCOPES);
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
```

This is as far as I have gotten, have mercy on me.

*** UPDATED ***

I have gotten to this far now, and feel I am closer.

```
<?php

require_once('google-api-php-client-2.2.1_PHP54/vendor/autoload.php');
$impersonateUser = 'XXX';
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array( 
Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER) ));
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . 'c_json' );

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setSubject($impersonateUser);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);

$dir = new Google_Service_Directory_Member($client);

$gPrimaryEmail = 'bob@bob.com';

$newUser = array( "email" => "bobby90210@bob.com", "role" => "MEMBER");

$results = $dir->members->insert($newUser);

print_r($results);

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in /var/www/newUserForGroup/addUser.php on line 19
```

*** SOLVED ***

With much disgust I have with how googles entire system is one big garbled mess, with zero answers, I managed to figure this out. If anyone else has this issue, this is it.

## Inserting a new Member into your Google Groups WITHOUT Oauth Login.

```
<?php

require_once('google-api-php-client-2.2.1_PHP54/vendor/autoload.php');
$impersonateUser = 'USER_EMAIL_WITH_ADMIN_ACCESS';

define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array( 
Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER))); // scope needed for function

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . 'json_c' ); // your json file

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setSubject($impersonateUser);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);

$key = "theaddress@theaddress.com"; // Your google groups "Healthtips@healthnow.com"

$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
$user = new Google_Service_Directory_Member(array('email' => 'ickabod@crane.com',
                    'kind' => 'admin#directory#member',
                    'role' => 'MEMBER',
                    'type' => 'USER'));


$list = $service->members->insert($key, $user);
```

Now I also must mention, that the main reason I was having issues was because I didn't have the Domain Wide Delegation set properly. You can find out how to do that [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

Answer (score 5):

*** SOLVED ***

With much disgust I have with how googles entire system is one big garbled mess, with zero answers, I managed to figure this out. If anyone else has this issue, this is it.

## Inserting a new Member into your Google Groups WITHOUT Oauth Login.

```
<?php

require_once('google-api-php-client-2.2.1_PHP54/vendor/autoload.php');
$impersonateUser = 'USER_EMAIL_WITH_ADMIN_ACCESS';

define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array( 
Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER))); // scope needed for function

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . 'json_c' ); // your json file

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setSubject($impersonateUser);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);

$key = "theaddress@theaddress.com"; // Your google groups "Healthtips@healthnow.com"

$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
$user = new Google_Service_Directory_Member(array('email' => 'ickabod@crane.com',
                    'kind' => 'admin#directory#member',
                    'role' => 'MEMBER',
                    'type' => 'USER'));


$list = $service->members->insert($key, $user);
```

Now I also must mention, that the main reason I was having issues was because I didn't have the Domain Wide Delegation set properly. You can find out how to do that [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

Cheers.

Comment: Lot of thanks, got the solution after searching since last week :)